# how to select all records that match some words within a string using mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

Hello am trying to implement and create a jobs feed in my system,

so i have a table with a column that holds the type of jobs a user wants to see on their feeds system

i represent that as a column name **"jobtype"**

**e.g web developer, software developer, graphics designer (please note the commas**)

and i also have a table  with a column **"exp"**

**e.g web developer, software developer, graphics designer (please note the commas)**

now i am trying to match a user with all these job types below

**web developer, software developer, graphic designer**

using

```
SELECT * FROM `jobs` WHERE exp LIKE '%web developer,software developer, graphics designer%'
```

first scenario when i test with exp field containing **web developer**, the job is returned by the sql statement because web developer is contained within the options

second scenario wen i test again with field exp containing **"web developer"** 
like this

**SELECT * FROM `jobs` WHERE exp LIKE '%software developer, graphics designer%, web developer,'**

the job is not returned because its third on the list

how can i make sure that when i search for key **web developer** in this list and arrangement below

```
%software developer, graphics designer,web developer,%
```

i get the required result

Thanks

Comment: your Keywords shouldn't be saved as a string in the database, instead, use a secondary table, that holds all Keywords for a specific Job, but every Keyword is one entry in the database

Comment: ok but how do you match to check if a word exist in a another group of words

Comment: Yep, this kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design

Comment: "ow do you match to check if a word exist in a another group of words"...since each word would be in a separate row of the table, you can just check that table for instances of that word, and it will test each row separately. Then you don't have to worry about comma-separated fields etc. As the others said, your design is de-normalised and that is a big reason you're having this problem. If you ever find yourself storing several values inside one field, it's time for a secondary table and a foreign key relationship instead.

Comment: you are not getting my question

Comment: its not an issue of poor design

Comment: how do you match the word water in a string of words that consists of  sand, stone, water using sql

Comment: "in a string of words that consists of sand, stone, water"....no, _you're_ not getting our point. In a correctly designed schema, that string would not exist, and so you wouldn't have this problem. Instead you've have separate rows with entries for each word associated with the user. So row 1 of the table might be "User ID: 1, Word: sand", row 2 might be "User ID: 1, Word: stone", row 3 might be "User ID: 2, Word: stone"...etc. So then you can very easily write a query to find all the users who have the word "stone" associated with them, without having to search within strings.

Comment: And if you wanted to search for a set of words instead of a single one, you could replace a clause like `= 'stone'` with  something like `IN ('stone', 'water')`. Much neater, and easier to do things like compile statistics, do proper sorting, etc. DB design principles are there for a reason, don't ignore it.

Comment: thanks guys, i appreciate, dont mean to argue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can search for keywords using the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `jobs` WHERE exp LIKE '%web developer%'
```

For multiple keywords you can use multiple `LIKE` statements:

```
SELECT * FROM `jobs` WHERE exp LIKE '%web developer%' OR exp LIKE '%graphic designer%'
```

Or if you want to make the query shorter you can use REGEXP:

```
SELECT * FROM `jobs` WHERE exp REGEXP 'web developer|graphic designer'
```

Found this solution here: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,392332,392950#msg-392950

More about REGEXP here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-regexps.htm

Comment: yes i have done this, but what of wen its like this SELECT * FROM `jobs` WHERE exp LIKE '%graphic designer, web developer%'

Comment: please note i am trying to target web developer

Comment: your answer you posted i have done before and works, but now i am trying for a set of words